# Alert me Project Online EventHandlers on TimesheetUpdated not fired.

Tags: office365, office365connectors, project-online

I got the following scenario:

- An Office 365 sharepoint PWA site.
- A WCF instance deployed on a IIS server at a Server A with a service that inherids TimesheetEventReceiver and implements methods OnUpdatedRemote and OnUpdated.
- I registered the EventHandler in the PWA web page for the event correctly (I see it as listed in the /_api/ProjectServer/EventHandlers). Also the Event which its linked to is the desired one (_api/ProjectServer/EventHandlers('guid')/Event shows the (int)PSEventID.TimesheetUpdated event).
- I tried the service from a console program that consumes it and checking that the WCF Service writes logs (just as proof of concept). Also the WCF application pool its set with a local administrator user so it doesn't matter who calls it.

The problem is that no matter how much timesheets I modify in the PWA I receive no calls to the web service.
Am I missing some Project Online configuration? Which one?
Where are the Project Online logs? I see no error during those operations.

Any suggestion/solution is welcomed.